# JavaScript array map while keeping original elements in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have this array.

```
const data = [
  { name: "A", age: "12" },
  { name: "B", age: "5" },
  { name: "C", age: "6" }
];
```

I want to add additional property called `key` to this array like this.

```
const data = [
  { name: "A", age: "12", key: "A12" },
  { name: "B", age: "5", key: "B5" },
  { name: "C", age: "6", key: "C6" }
];
```

I tired this map function and output is not the one I expect. How do I achieve this using JS map function..

```js
const data = [
  { name: "A", age: "12"},
  { name: "B", age: "5"},
  { name: "C", age: "6"}
];

console.log(
  "MAP",
  data.map(element => (element.key = element.name + element.age))
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return `element` as well using the comma operator:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "A", age: "12"},
  { name: "B", age: "5"},
  { name: "C", age: "6"}
];

console.log(data.map(element => (element.key = element.name + element.age, element)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Or just change your `map` callback to make it simpler with destructuring:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "A", age: "12"},
  { name: "B", age: "5"},
  { name: "C", age: "6"}
];

console.log(data.map(({ name, age }) => ({ name, age, key: name + age})));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to return an object from the `map` callback:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "A", age: "12"},
  { name: "B", age: "5"},
  { name: "C", age: "6"}
];

console.log(
  data.map(({ name, age }) => ({ name, age, key: name + age }))
);
```

If you wish to mutate the existing objects, then use `forEach` instead of `.map`:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "A", age: "12"},
  { name: "B", age: "5"},
  { name: "C", age: "6"}
];

data.forEach((obj) => {
  obj.key = obj.name + obj.age;
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to do this and the `Array.map` is by far the most concise and clean way to do it as already provided. Here are few other methods:

```js
 const data = [ { name: "A", age: "12" }, { name: "B", age: "5" }, { name: "C", age: "6" } ];

let from = Array.from(data, ({name, age}) => ({name, age, key: name+age}))
let assign = data.map(({name, age}) => Object.assign({name, age}, {key: name+age}))

console.log('from: ', from)
console.log('assign: ', assign)
```

If you want to generate a key from all `values` (assuming all are primitives) you can also do this:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "A", age: "12", city: 'Miami' },  // "key": "A12Miami"
  { name: "B", age: "2", gender: 'M'},      // "key": "B2M"
];

let all = data.map(obj => 
  ({...obj, ...Object.fromEntries([['key', Object.values(obj).join('')]])}))

console.log(all)
```

This way you do not have to specify or care about the pop names etc.